# Apply filter to future dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, filter

I have a column of dates as such

```
1. 01-Mar-2012
2. 01-Apr-2012
3. 01-May-2012
4. 01-Jun-2012
5. 01-Jul-2012
6. 01-Aug-2012
7. 01-Sep-2012
8. 01-Oct-2012
9. 01-Nov-2012
10. 01-Dec-2012
11. 01-Jan-2013
12. 01-Mar-2013
13. 01-Apr-2013
14. 01-May-2013
15. 01-Jun-2013
16. 01-Jul-2013
17. 01-Aug-2013
18. 01-Sep-2013
19. 01-Oct-2013
20. 01-Nov-2013
21. 01-Dec-2013
```

I simply want to apply a filter to the data so that the records stop at a certain month (lets say April for now) in 2013.

I've tried the following but can't think of the last part:

```
WHERE DATEPART(year, Q.TermDate) <= DATEPART(year, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) 
AND DATEPART(MONTH, Q.TermDate) <= ...)
```

Can anyone please give a suggestion?

Comment: It sounds like OP wants to take a month as a parameter, and base the logic on that integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a year and month parameter:

```
DECLARE @siYear smallint
DECLARE @tiMonth tinyint
SET @siYear = 2013
SET @tiMonth = 4

SELECT
  MyTable.MyDateValue
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  MyTable.MyDateValue <= CAST(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@siYear AS varchar(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@tiMonth AS varchar(2)), 2) + '-01' AS datetime)
```

For readers of my opinion of <= vs < for date boundaries, change the predicate to:

```
WHERE
      MyTable.MyDateValue < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@siYear AS varchar(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@tiMonth AS varchar(2)), 2) + '-01' AS datetime))
```

Comment: Just a slight modification made it work for what I need. Thanks again. WHERE Q.TermDate <= CAST(CAST(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) + '-01' AS VARCHAR)AS DATETIME)

Answer (score 2):

If these are already datetimes, then just use a <=

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TermDate <= '01-Apr-2013'
```

Comment: This is not Oracle. Let's try to use ISO-8601.  WHERE TermDate <= '2013-04-01' /*Incidentally, I prefer to use WHERE TermDate < '2013-04-02', instead of the equality, so that '2013-04-01 11:00' is found in that case, whereas the <= may introduce bugs. It depends upon the source data*/

Comment: I was merely sticking with the example, but yes, the date should be written in a more standard sense. The system should be able to interpret it either way, though

Answer (score 1):

You can write your statement like this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),TermDate,112) <= '201304'
```

But this will not use any index that you could have on your `TermDate` column. So you can just do:

```
WHERE TermDate < '20130501'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straight forward;

```
SELECT * FROM Q WHERE TermDate<'2013-04-01';
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9915c/2).